# How to modify the alpha bibliography style to show truncated first names after the surnames?

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I am searching for a way to make my references such that:

- the layout of the citation call-outs follows standard `alpha` style, and
- the layout of the formatted bibliographic entries is slightly non-standard, as follows. For an article published in 1998 by A. Braham and D. Avid, I want the citation call-out to be "standard alpha", i.e., `[BA98]`, and the list of authors in the formatted bibliographic entry to be shown as `Braham, A., and Avid, D.` Currently, the name list format is `A. Braham and D. Avid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `alpha.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `alpha-mod.bst`. (Don't edit an original, unrenamed file of the TeX distribution directly.)
- In the file `alpha-mod.bst`, find the function `format.names`. (In my copy of the file, this function starts on line 187.)

  In this function, find the following line:

  ```
      { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```
- In this line, change  the string `"{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"` to `"{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f.}"`.

  Even if you're not familiar with BibTeX's in-fix syntax, I trust you can guess what this change does: Instead of telling BibTeX to place the first name *before* the other components of the author's full name, BibTeX is now instructed to place a comma and the truncated first name *after* all other components. (Aside: In BibTeX jargon, a "full" name may have up to four components: first or given name (or names), a von-component, the surname, and a junior-component.)
- Save the file `alpha-mod.bst` either in the directory that contains your main tex file or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{alpha}` to `\bibliographystyle{alpha-mod}` and perform a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing.

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{ab02, author = "Anne Author and Brenda Buthor",
    title = "Thoughts", year = 3002}
@misc{abc03, author = "Anne Author and Brenda Buthor and Carla Cuthor",
   title = "Further Thoughts", year = 3003}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliographystyle{alpha-mod}

\begin{document}
\cite{ab02}, \cite{abc03}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I work in Overleaf, is it also possible to find the alpha.bst file there?

Comment: @Sven - I'm afraid I don't know Overleaf at all. If you can't find it in Overleaf, you could download `alpha.bst` from the CTAN (Central TeX Archive Network) at http://mirrors.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/base/alpha.bst.