# Customizing bibliography style alpha while using BibTeX

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, amsart

I am trying to customize the bibliography style alpha, preferably in `amsart` (or ams class, in general), while I'm using BibTeX, since I'm using `reference management software` like `Bibdesk`. In the alpha style we have something like the following example:

> [Ein05] Albert Einstein, Zur Elektrodynamik ..., 1905.

Now, I want to reorder the author name as follows:

> [Ein05] Einstein, A.: Zur Elektrodynamik ..., 1905.

That is, the last name should come first, then the first letter of the first name, and then colon. The rest could be kept as it is in the `alpha` style.

How can I customize it such that anyone could see the result? Because I don't want to customize it just on my machine.

Comment: Oh sorry! I just made bold the changes so that the changes are clear. I am interested in your solution, however it would be great to replace the comma with colon after the abbreviated name.

Comment: If I do that then no one else could run the source. I am sharing the tex file, so I need a solution that can be applied on the current tex file, independent of the distribution.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, I can share bst file. That's not a problem. I thought these changes would be applicable at just the local machine.

Comment: @Mico Can I edit another style to achieve my favourite style I gave in my post? I played around with the bst file to change the dot to colon after the author names, but I wasn't successful.

Comment: @Mico My question its: can I create a similar style as alpha with the difference that instead of the dot one would have colon? So not to change the alpha, but rather create a new one?

Comment: The question of how to change the display of authors' names from `FullGivenName Surname` to `Surname, InitialLetterofGivenName` has already been raised (and answered) in [How to modify the alpha bibliography style to show truncated first names after the surnames?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/537406/5001)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the name format changes are quite straightforward once you are familiar with the arcane BibTeX language, the colon thing is a bit more difficult to achieve within the framework of `alpha.bst`.

For the name format you replace

```
    { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
```

with

```
    { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, f.}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
```

See for example also [How to modify the alpha bibliography style to show truncated first names after the surnames?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/537406/35864).

Here's what I would do. It's a bit tricky to describe in words, so here is the `diff` to `alpha.bst` (including the one-line change for the name format)

```
--- alpha.bst   2010-12-09 04:18:56.000000000 +0100
+++ alpha-fg.bst    2020-06-20 21:23:26.062881200 +0200
@@ -1,3 +1,7 @@
+%% alpha-fg
+%% 2020-06-20 MW
+%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/550269/35864
+%% alpha.bst with family, given order, given initials and colon
 % BibTeX standard bibliography style `alpha'
    % Version 0.99b (8-Dec-10 release) for BibTeX versions 0.99a or later.
    % Copyright (C) 1984, 1985, 1988, 2010 Howard Trickey and Oren Patashnik.
@@ -35,13 +39,14 @@
   {}
   { label extra.label sort.label }
 
-INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }
+INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block after.colon }
 
 FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
 { #0 'before.all :=
   #1 'mid.sentence :=
   #2 'after.sentence :=
   #3 'after.block :=
+  #4 'after.colon :=
 }
 
 STRINGS { s t }
@@ -50,14 +55,20 @@
 { 's :=
   output.state mid.sentence =
     { ", " * write$ }
-    { output.state after.block =
-        { add.period$ write$
+    { output.state after.colon =
+        { ": " * write$
           newline$
-          "\newblock " write$
-        }
-        { output.state before.all =
-            'write$
-            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
+          "\newblock " write$ }
+        { output.state after.block =
+            { add.period$ write$
+              newline$
+              "\newblock " write$
+            }
+            { output.state before.all =
+               'write$
+               { add.period$ " " * write$ }
+              if$
+            }
           if$
         }
       if$
@@ -107,6 +118,13 @@
   if$
 }
 
+FUNCTION {new.colon.block}
+{ output.state before.all =
+    'skip$
+    { after.colon 'output.state := }
+  if$
+}
+
 FUNCTION {new.sentence}
 { output.state after.block =
     'skip$
@@ -190,7 +208,7 @@
   s num.names$ 'numnames :=
   numnames 'namesleft :=
     { namesleft #0 > }
-    { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
+    { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, f.}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
       nameptr #1 >
         { namesleft #1 >
             { ", " * t * }
@@ -540,7 +558,7 @@
 FUNCTION {article}
 { output.bibitem
   format.authors "author" output.check
-  new.block
+  new.colon.block
   format.title "title" output.check
   new.block
   crossref missing$
@@ -568,7 +586,7 @@
       if$
     }
   if$
-  new.block
+  new.colon.block
   format.btitle "title" output.check
   crossref missing$
     { format.bvolume output
@@ -592,7 +610,7 @@
 FUNCTION {booklet}
 { output.bibitem
   format.authors output
-  new.block
+  new.colon.block
   format.title "title" output.check
   howpublished address new.block.checkb
   howpublished output
@@ -614,7 +632,7 @@
       if$
     }
   if$
-  new.block
+  new.colon.block
   format.btitle "title" output.check
   crossref missing$
     { format.bvolume output
@@ -640,7 +658,7 @@
 FUNCTION {incollection}
 { output.bibitem
   format.authors "author" output.check
-  new.block
+  new.colon.block
   format.title "title" output.check
   new.block
   crossref missing$
@@ -666,7 +684,7 @@
 FUNCTION {inproceedings}
 { output.bibitem
   format.authors "author" output.check
-  new.block
+  new.colon.block
   format.title "title" output.check
   new.block
   crossref missing$
@@ -711,7 +729,7 @@
     }
     { format.authors output.nonnull }
   if$
-  new.block
+  new.colon.block
   format.btitle "title" output.check
   author empty$
     { organization empty$
@@ -736,7 +754,7 @@
 FUNCTION {mastersthesis}
 { output.bibitem
   format.authors "author" output.check
-  new.block
+  new.colon.block
   format.title "title" output.check
   new.block
   "Master's thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull
@@ -751,6 +769,7 @@
 FUNCTION {misc}
 { output.bibitem
   format.authors output
+  new.colon.block
   title howpublished new.block.checkb
   format.title output
   howpublished new.block.checka
@@ -765,7 +784,7 @@
 FUNCTION {phdthesis}
 { output.bibitem
   format.authors "author" output.check
-  new.block
+  new.colon.block
   format.btitle "title" output.check
   new.block
   "PhD thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull
@@ -783,7 +802,7 @@
     { organization output }
     { format.editors output.nonnull }
   if$
-  new.block
+  new.colon.block
   format.btitle "title" output.check
   format.bvolume output
   format.number.series output
@@ -815,7 +834,7 @@
 FUNCTION {techreport}
 { output.bibitem
   format.authors "author" output.check
-  new.block
+  new.colon.block
   format.title "title" output.check
   new.block
   format.tr.number output.nonnull
@@ -830,7 +849,7 @@
 FUNCTION {unpublished}
 { output.bibitem
   format.authors "author" output.check
-  new.block
+  new.colon.block
   format.title "title" output.check
   new.block
   note "note" output.check
```

The idea is to add a new punctuation state for the colon to the punctuation handling of the style. We then define a new function that sets this colon state and call that function after `format.authors`/`format.editors`.

You can download the modified `alpha-fg.bst` from https://gist.github.com/moewew/98f5aee969725d21d1f8da0355d50081.

With that file

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{uthor,
  author    = {Anne Uthor and Anne Elk},
  title     = {Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet},
  publisher = {Pub \& Co.},
  year      = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\cite{uthor}
\bibliographystyle{alpha-fg}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: [UE80] Uthor, A. and Elk, A.: Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet. Pub & Co., 1980.]

---

Just for fun, here's how you would apply the same changes with `biblatex`, where styles can be customised directly from the document preamble.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=alphabetic,
  giveninits=true,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{uthor,
  author    = {Anne Uthor and Anne Elk},
  title     = {Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet},
  publisher = {Pub \& Co.},
  year      = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{uthor}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Although I don't understand anything in the code of the bst file, I think this is a great answer! Thank you very much!

Comment: Just a short question: I see that the title of the papers (or other elements) are italic. How can I remove it and have normal font?

Comment: Another question: how can I make the volume number bold?

Comment: @Astrolabe It is preferred to ask about only one thing per question on this site. I suggest you open up new questions about those two points.

Comment: I opened up a new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550400/customizing-the-bst-file-making-volume-number-bold

Comment: @moewe - The issue of how to change the display of an author's or editor's full name when using the `alpha` bib style is an exact duplicate of [How to modify the alpha bibliography style to show truncated first names after the surnames?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/537406/5001). Maybe streamline your answer to address "just" the far more involved issue of how to display a colon instead of a period after the author block?

Comment: @Mico I decided to leave it in, but make the change more explicit and link to your answer. Most people who are interested in the code will probably be able to tell what does what with that info. I'm not a big fan of retroactively changing questions and answers, so I'd to leave it at that.