# Customizing the bst file - disable the italic form of the elements

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

In a [previous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550269/customizing-bibliography-style-alpha-while-using-bibtex) post I asked how one can customize an alpha style-type bst file.

Now, I would like to know how I can change the font of some element (e.g., the titles). In particular, some elements are in italic form. How can I remove that?

Comment: Do you want to disable italicization *globally* in the bibliography, or just for some elements? If it's the latter, which ones might they be?

Comment: @Mico I would like to disable italicization globally. I thought, bolding the volume number is rather a minor change, therefore, I asked both question in one post.

Comment: @Mico Query edited. I will post the other query separately later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you're using a modified version of the file `alpha.bst`. It contains a function called `emphasize`, which is invoked in more than a dozen different instances throughout the bst file.

Rather than edit these dozen+ different instances, I suggest disabling the function itself. In the modified bst file, look for the following code block:

```
FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\em " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

(Depending on the vintage of your bst file, it may say `{ "\emph{" swap$ * "}" * }` instead of `{ "{\em " swap$ * "}" * }`.)

Change the code block to

```
FUNCTION {emphasize}
{}
```

which, effectively, makes it an empty shell that does nothing at all -- exactly what you want it to be, right?

Comment: Thanks! I opened up the new query: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550442/customizing-the-bst-file-making-the-volume-number-bold