# Customizing the bst file - making the volume number bold

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

In a series of posts (see [[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550269/customizing-bibliography-style-alpha-while-using-bibtex)] and [[2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550400/customizing-the-bst-file-disable-the-italic-form-of-the-elements)) I asked how one can make one's own bibliography style.

Now, I would like to make the volume number bold, which is quite usual in many journals. What can I change in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that the bibliography style (bst) file you've been modifying is called `alpha-mod.bst`. I suggest you proceed as follows.

- First, locate the BibTeX function called `emphasize`. (This function may have been reduced to a stub in an earlier modification round.) Below this function, insert the following code block:

  ```
   FUNCTION {embolden}
   { duplicate$ empty$
       { pop$ "" }
       { "{\bfseries " swap$ * "}" * }
     if$
   }
  ```
- Second, locate the following line

  ```
   FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
  ```

  which denotes the start of the definition of, you guessed it, the `format.vol.num.pages` BibTeX function.

  The immediate next line in the bst file should be

  ```
  { volume field.or.null
  ```

  Change it to

  ```
   { volume embolden field.or.null
  ```

That's it. Don't forget to save the bst file.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Another question came into my mind. Is there any clever way to abbreviate the journal names automatically? If yes, I will ask it separately.

Comment: Of course, I mean the accepted abbreviation of the journal names, not any arbitrary ones.

Comment: Is that possible?

Comment: @Astrolabe - Sure it's possible. Lots of bib styles provide extensive lists of abbreviated journal names; see, e.g.,, `elsarticle-harv.bst`. OTOH, many other bib styles provide no such list.

Comment: But, how should I combine this with my own bib style?

Comment: @Astrolabe - Please ask a new question.

Comment: I post a new question regarding this. I appreciate your patience!

Comment: Any suggestion on my new post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550650/abbreviation-of-journal-names-using-bst

Comment: @Astrolabe - Sorry, I don't how to go about solving the issues raised by your follow-up query.