# Abbreviation of journal names using bst

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

In a series of posts (see [[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550269/customizing-bibliography-style-alpha-while-using-bibtex)], [[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550400/customizing-the-bst-file-disable-the-italic-form-of-the-elements)], and [[3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550442/customizing-the-bst-file-making-the-volume-number-bold)]) I asked how one can create one's own bibliography style.

Now, I would like to understand how I can abbreviate the journal names cleverly. I'm using a `reference management software`, i.e., `Bibdesk`, which saves the complete name of the journal, e.g. `Physical Review A`. But, one should use most of the time the abbreviated form of the journal names. In this case: `Phys. Rev. A`.

Question is: how can I integrate this in my own bibliography style (which I learned in the previous posts how to make it)?

Comment: This is usually implemented with a `journal.abbrev` function which is basically one big set of nested `if$` statements. See e.g. the `ACM-Reference-Format.bst` for an example.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get how I can integrate this into my own bib style.

Comment: Related/Duplicate? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111724/is-there-a-transparent-way-to-automatically-abbreviate-journal-names

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Not a duplicate: that shows how to allow abbreviations in the `.bib` file to expand to fuller (possibly abbreviated) names. This question asks how to abbreviate long names themselves.

Comment: @AlanMunn That doesn't seem clear to me from the question. So, you are saying that the desire is to be presented with a full journal name and have the software generate the abbreviation?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes that seems to be what the question says.

Comment: @AlanMunn You're right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic technique for implementing journal abbreviations is a function containing a big list of nested `if$` statements with each `if$` corresponding to a pair of full journal names and their corresponding abbreviation. Here's an example of a function that abbreviates two journal names. Notice that for each long journal name there may be multiple versions based on what the input field may be in your `.bib` file. For example, `\&` and `and` are both possible in the first journal name, and `IPA`, `{IPA}`, and `International Phonetic Association` are possible for the second journal name.

This function must appear *before* any function that calls it, so it must precede both the `article` function and the `format.article.crossref` function.

```
FUNCTION { journal.abbrev } {
      journal   "Natural Language and Linguistic Theory" = { "NLLT" } 
       { journal "Natural Language \& Linguistic Theory" = { "NLLT" }
          { journal "Journal of the International Phonetic Association" = { "Jour. IPA" }
            { journal "Journal of the {IPA}" = { "Jour. IPA" }
               { journal "Journal of the IPA" = { "Jour. IPA" }
                  { journal }  if$ } if$ } if$ } if$} if$}
```

Now we use this function to pass to the `article` function for the journal title formatting (the following adapted from the `alpha.bst` which is your base) instead of just passing `journal`.

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal.abbrev emphasize "journal" output.check
      format.vol.num.pages output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

Since this style oddly also allows crossref links to articles you also need to change that function:

```
FUNCTION {format.article.crossref}
{ key empty$
    { journal empty$
        { "need key or journal for " cite$ * " to crossref " * crossref *
          warning$
          ""
        }
        { "In {\em " journal.abbrev * "\/}" * }
      if$
    }
    { "In " key * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
```

To remove the `,` that appears after the journal title requires some extra work.

First we need to add an extra flag for the state of being after a journal title, we first add this to the list of integer variables:

```
INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block after.journal }
```

then assign it a value:

```
FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=
  #4 'after.journal :=
}
```

Now we modify the `output.nonnull` function to check for `after.journal`:

```
FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
output.state after.journal =
 {" " * write$ }
 {
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
        { add.period$ write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
}
if$
  s
}
```

Finally we change the `article` function to set the state to `after.journal`.

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { after.journal 'output.state :=
      journal.abbrev emphasize "journal" output.check
      format.vol.num.pages output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

Sample document (the modified `.bst` file I've named `alpha-abbrv.bst`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{Boeckx2001scope,
    Author = {Boeckx, Cedric},
    Journal = {Natural Language and Linguistic Theory},
    Number = {3},
    Pages = {503--548},
    Title = {Scope reconstruction and {A}-movement},
    Volume = {19},
    Year = {2001}}


@article{MayrDavies2011,
    Author = {Mayr, Robert and Davies, Hannah},
    Journal = {Journal of the International Phonetic Association},
    Number = {1},
    Pages = {1--25},
    Title = {A cross-dialectal acoustic study of the monophthongs and diphthongs of {Welsh}},
    Volume = {41},
    Year = {2011}}


@article{AounChoueiri2000,
    Author = {Joseph Aoun and Lisa Choueiri},
    Journal = {Natural Language \& Linguistic Theory},
    Pages = {1--39},
    Title = {Epithets},
    Volume = {18},
    Year = {2000}}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{alpha-abbrv}
\begin{document}
\cite{MayrDavies2011,AounChoueiri2000,Boeckx2001scope}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer! How can I get rid of the comma after the abbreviation?

Comment: I ask this because the abbreviations I used end up with a dot. This is sufficient. The comma is then not needed.

Comment: @Astrolabe I've updated the answer.

Comment: Oh, there is a problem. Because, I tried to replace the dot after the author names by colon in the first link I added in the post. Now, the colon is gone. I played around with that, but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: @Astrolabe Well that's not surprising since that answer also added an extra flag. So you just need to make sure the two flags have different values: instead of `#4 'after.journal :=` (which is assigned to your `'after.colon` variable in your first answer) use `#5 'after.journal :=` instead inside the `init.states.consts` Remember also that your list of `INTEGERS` must also include the `after.colon` variable.  I was modifying the `alpha.bst`, not following all the individual modifications you made in each question.

Comment: I exactly did so, but it didn't work. I think the problem is in `FUNCTION {output.nonnull}`, because in link below I changed it accordingly: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550269/customizing-bibliography-style-alpha-while-using-bibtex

Comment: I need to make `FUNCTION {output.nonnull}` consistent for two changes at the same time. I'm trying to do so ...

Comment: @Astrolabe Well it's just a nested `if$` statement, so just make sure the nesting is correct.

Comment: Could you please give an example? I don't get it.

Comment: @Astrolabe The syntax is `A B = { true part} {false part} if$`.  And inside each false part are the other conditionals, so two would be `A B = {true} {C D = {true} {false} if$ } if$`, etc.